# Is there a default parameter for getting the name of a jasper report?

Tags: jasper-reports

Jasper reports have some default parameters. Is there one containing the name of the report?

Comment: what do you mean by `default parameters` ? you have to pass params and their values to access in jasper report whatever you like and read from param tag there

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57327088/5111904